# StandardOutput returning empty string in C#

Tags: c#, windows, command-prompt

Similar questions about `STDOUT` (`STandarOUTput`) have been asked before. But in my case, there is no exception, still, the output result is an empty string.

Using the following code, I am successfully able to execute the EXE. The Exe returns some output on the command window, which I can also see. Now I want to read that output in a string. In the code below, the `strOutput` is an empty string (even though I can see some output on the command window).

Here is my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

try
{
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;             
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\exeFilePath\exedrivermanager.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;         

    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    myProcess.Start();
    string strOutput = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //THIS RETURNS AN EMPTY STRING.

    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Output: " + strOutput);

    //Wait for process to finish
    myProcess.WaitForExit();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I realized that it is not possible to write the output to a file even with the command line. It seems that the called program is never terminated completely. The called program leaves the command line as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Can you make the process to also write the output in a file and read the produced output from there?

Comment: If you **see** the output then it **has NOT been redirected**. Assuming the called program does not allocate its own console (which might be possible) you may also check the error stream

Comment: @BogdanDoicin: I tried to pass `> D:\\IntallLog.txt` as an argument but the file was not created. I am not sure, what the correct way of writing output to a file in this case.

Comment: @skm first you modify the original program to write the output in a file then you use the second program to read from the file.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin: I do not have control on the original program  (the program which I am executing via this C# program). I can only make changes in this C# prorgram. *Not sure If I understood you right.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. If you had control over the original program, I think the file method would have been a good alternative.

Comment: Have you tried running exedrivermanager from the command line & seeing if you can redirect the output to a file?

Comment: @PaulF: Now i have tried to write the output on a file from command line and even that doesn't work. I think that the `exedrivermanager` does not exit completely. I see the cursor blinking.

Comment: If the output is not redirected when running from the command line then it would appear that the output is not being written to the standard output stream. Have you tried redirecting stderr to a file _"exedrivermanager 2>myfile.txt"_

Comment: Another possibility is that the output is buffered until the application does correctly exit.

Comment: @PaulF: Sorry I did not get what you mean. In one of the answers below, Ali has suggested using `RedirectStandardError` but the program never enters in it.

Comment: Did you add the call to BeginErrorReadLine as shown in Ilyakom's answer

Comment: @PaulF: Yes, i did it now. But the `e.data` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best practice to write the exec output in external text file and then read from this file using the normal way to read text files.

Comment: How does the output get written to an external file?

Answer (score 0):

I have found subscribing to the events more reliable. And as Adriano said, you probably should redirect error stream as well. Here is a snippet that should help:

```
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true; 
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += process_Output;
process.ErrorDataReceived += process_Error;

void process_Output(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Data would contain a line
    var outputLine = e.Data;
}

void process_Error(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var errorLine = e.Data;
}
```

Comment: I added your suggestion in the code and put a breakpoint inside both the methods but the program never enters in it.

Comment: here should be `process.BeginOutputReadLine()` call as well

Comment: Did you redirect RedirectStandardError as well, I have updated it above. Also, you need to add those lines before calling myProcess.Start().

Comment: @Ali: I added your recommendaion but still it did not eneter in those two methods.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's wrong you can try to read ErrorStream as well. For example, MongoDB restore util write all console info to ErrorStream instead of OutputStream. I would recommend you to try to use event listeners:

```
           var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = exePath,
                Arguments = " ", //this could be tricky
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            try
            {
                using (var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;

                    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => Logger.Warn("OutputStream: " + args.Data);
                    process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => Logger.Warn("ErrorStream: " + args.Data);

                    if (!process.Start())
                    {
                        // not started
                    }

                    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

                    if (!process.WaitForExit(60_000))
                    {
                        \\Process ended with timeout. 60_000";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                \\ O_o
                throw;
            }
```